# problems getting filedescriptor in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm having problems with mapping a file into memory. I somehow can't get the Filedescriptor. This is what I try to do:

```
char* Logfile::open(){

    // get file size
    struct stat st;
    stat(name.c_str(), &st);

    size = st.st_size;

    // get file descriptor
    file_descriptor = fstream::open(name.c_str(), fstream::flags = O_RDONLY); //open(name.c_str(), 0_RDONLY);
    if(file_descriptor < 0){
        cerr << "Error obtaining file descriptor for: " << name.c_str() << endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    // memory map part
    start = (char*) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, file_descriptor, 0);
    if(start == NULL){
        cerr << "Error memory-mapping the file\n";
        //close(file_descriptor);
        return NULL;
    }

    return start;
}
```

The Compiler keeps telling me:

../src/Logfile.cpp: In member function ‘char* Logfile::open()’:
../src/Logfile.cpp:31: error: insufficient contextual information to determine type

Comment: Sorry, it's the line: file_descriptor = fstream::open(name.c_str(), fstream::flags = O_RDONLY);

Answer (score 1):

If by fstream you mean `std::fstream`, there is no support for file descriptors, and no static or  non-member function called `open()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 fstream::flags = O_RDONLY
```

Doesn't mean anything.

If you want to use a *read-only filestream* use `ifstream` instead of `fstream`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that my own Implementations of open() and close() caused a conflict. I renamed them to mapopen() and mapclose() and now it's working like this:

> char* Logfile::mapopen(){
>
> ```
> // get file size
> struct stat st;
> stat(name.c_str(), &st);
>
> size = st.st_size;
>
> // get file descriptor
> file_descriptor = open(name.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
> ```
>
> //open(name.c_str(), 0_RDONLY);
>       if(file_descriptor < 0){
>           cerr << "Error obtaining file descriptor for: " << name.c_str() <<
>   endl;
>           return NULL;
>       }
>
> ```
> // memory map part
> start = (char*) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED,
> ```
>
> file_descriptor, 0);
>       if(start == NULL){
>           cerr << "Error memory-mapping the file\n";
>           close(file_descriptor);
>           return NULL;
>       }
>
> ```
> return start; }
> ```